# iis 8 php form submit with url encoded char results in error 302

Tags: php, windows, iis, iis-8

Hi I am  using php on IIS 8

My issue is when i post a form to my server if there is url encoding like so , the server doent process it and just gives  302 error.

```
https://www.alpha.com/footer/data.php?name=sdfsdf&agency=sdfsdfd&email=pl%40hotmail.com&allair=on&airline=HA&airline=OL&airline=JU&airline%5B%5D=AZ&airline%5B%5D=KM&airline%5B%5D=SN"
```

but if  i use post man and  post it like this it goes through

```
https://www.alpha.com/footer/data.php?name=sdfsdf&agency=sdfsdfd&email=pl@hotmail.com&allair=on&airline[]=HA&airline[]=OL&airline[]=JU
```

Please help me i have no clue on how to get IIS to accept a url encoded data i found out that  %  is the problem ..

Comment: 302 indicates a redirect, not strictly an error. Instead of the annoying "please help me" bytext, explain how that's an issue, and take a peek into the logs at least.

Comment: the url to which the data that is being submitted to is correct   so if i submit data  with urldecoded  chaacteds such as   % eg email=donald%40hotmail.com   than it just redirects and doesnt insert the data ...   but if i submit data  that does not have the above eg  like so  email=donald@hotmail.com   to the same url  the data gets saved into the db  without issues and there is no redirect 302 message...